# Sending an alert email if time for a curl command exceeds 1 sec

Tags: command-line, bash, time

I am trying to a write one liner for sending an alert email if the time taken for curl command exceeds 1 sec.

```
if time curl {URI} > 1; then mailx -r me@domain.tld -s ALERT; fi
```

How since **time** command returns more than just a numeric value, this fails.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, the result of *curl* does not seem to matter.

So I propose to **kill** the command if it spans more than one second by using **timeout**. Here is the **one-liner**:

```
timeout 1s curl {URI} || mailx -r me@domain.tld -s ALERT
```

If it timeouts, it returns an error and the mailx command is run.

No tested but that should work.

Comment: If this answer your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd save the PID of the `curl` process, `sleep` a second and just test whether it's still running with `kill`:

```bsh
curl … &
pid=$!
sleep 1
if kill -0 $pid &>/dev/null; then
  mailx -r me@domain.tld -s ALERT
fi
```

You can test this easily with `sleep 1` or `sleep 2` respectively:

```bsh
$ sleep 1 & pid=$!; sleep 1; if kill -0 $pid &>/dev/null; then echo running; fi
[1] 27520
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
$ sleep 2 & pid=$!; sleep 1; if kill -0 $pid &>/dev/null; then echo running; fi
[1] 27599
running
```

Answer (score 1):

Curl has an option for this, --max-time (and --connect-time, if you want to control time spend in the connect phase on the session). If timeout occurs, curl will return error-code 28.

So something like this:

```
curl --max-time 60 <URL>
if [ $? -eq 28 ]
then 
  mailx -r me@domain.tld -s ALERT
fi
```

should do it.

I found this site [Everything Curl](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-timeouts.html) which describes the capabilities of Curl.